# Salesforce large query conditions: query 20000 contacts by emails and update fields

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a csv file which has 20000 email addresses in it. I need to update some fields on these contacts. the dataloader is not suitable as I don't have the ID field of these email addresses. query in small groups will probably need to repeat more than 100 times.

**What is the easiest way to query and update the contacts if I only have a large number of email address as query condition?**

Comment: I would import it into mysql database then you can very easily add any columns you like and edit them by simple queires. You can even add indexes. (And if you want csv again, you can export it to csv afterwards)

Comment: Hi Jan, I don't quite get it. how could I get the id fields of all these contacts easily from over 2 million contacts in total?

Comment: will you show me a single line (anonymized) of your csv? i bet you can easil import it into some DB system and just add a column with primary key on it and autoincrement. And so you will end up with a DB of 2 mil. rows with IDs and you will be able to do what you want to do. Jftr: 2 mil rows is not a problem at all.